# Could NOT find Boost error

Tags: boost

I want to install RGBDemo 0.7. I installed all necessary packages (libfreenect, PCL,openni,nite,sensorkinect,opencv 2.3.1)
When I entered the command `./linux_configure.sh` in the RGBDemo directory, I get the error below:

```
OpenCV > 2.2 found, enable advanced features.

OpenCV > 2.3.0 found, enable flann fix features.

-- Could NOT find Boost

CMake Error at /usr/share/pcl-1.7/PCLConfig.cmake:42 (message):

  common is required but boost was not found

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  /usr/share/pcl-1.7/PCLConfig.cmake:495 (pcl_report_not_found)

  /usr/share/pcl-1.7/PCLConfig.cmake:652 (find_external_library)

  nestk/cmake/find_nestk_deps.cmake:99 (FIND_PACKAGE)

  build/nestk/UseEmbeddedNestk.cmake:23 (INCLUDE)

  nestk/CMakeLists.txt:67 (INCLUDE)




CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to 

NOTFOUND.

Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:

GLUT_LIB

    linked by target "Sample-Players" in directory /home/hasan/RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/nestk

/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players

    linked by target "CircleControl" in directory /home/hasan/RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/nestk

/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/CircleControl

    linked by target "Boxes" in directory /home/hasan/RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/nestk

/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Boxes

LIBDL

    linked by target "OpenNI" in directory /home/hasan/RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/nestk

/deps/openni/Source/OpenNI

LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY

    linked by target "freenect" in directory /home/hasan/RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/nestk

/deps/libfreenect/src

    linked by target "freenectstatic" in directory /home/hasan/RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/nestk

/deps/libfreenect/src

    linked by target "OpenNI" in directory /home/hasan/RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/nestk

/deps/openni/Source/OpenNI


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Program configured in directory build.

Now go into build/ and run make.
```

I really searched in Google but I couldn't find any solution... Thanks in advance ...

Comment: have you installed boost library